# How to make sum of 2 columns in a subquery in sql?

Tags: mysql

i want to make a coulmn which show the multiplication of number_ordered and price but when i use this query

```
SELECT  customer_num AS 'Customer Number' , 
        order_num AS 'Order Number' ,
        order_date AS 'Order Date' , 
        (SELECT SUM(quoted_price * num_ordered ) FROM tbl_order_line ) AS 'ORDER_TOTAL'
FROM tbl_orders ;
```

it gives me same record for every field
this is tbl_order_line

```
    CREATE TABLE tbl_order_line
(
    order_num       CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    part_num          CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    num_ordered     DECIMAL(3,0) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    quoted_price    DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(order_num, part_num),
    FOREIGN KEY(order_num) REFERENCES tbl_orders(order_num),
    FOREIGN KEY(part_num)  REFERENCES tbl_part(part_num)
);
```

and this is tbl_orders

```
    CREATE TABLE tbl_orders
(
    order_num           CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date          DATE NOT NULL,
    customer_num        CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_num) REFERENCES tbl_customer(customer_num) 
);
```

[image: expected result]   [image: result i get]

Comment: Can you show us structure of output that you expect?

Comment: why don't you use left join instead of subquerying

Comment: i have been told to use subquery not a join @Hatik

Comment: I concur with @Hatik.  Left join on tbl_order_line.order_num = tbl_orders.order_num.  You'll need a "group by order_num", and keep the SUM, but move it to the outermost SELECT

Comment: Then you'll need a way to associate the order_num value in the subquery with the order_num value in the outer query.  Can you add a "where order_num = tbl_order.order_num" to it?

Comment: @ blasanka i uploaded the question you can now see the question edited

Comment: in that case you will need to specify the rows on which to use sum for each row of `tbl_orders` as @J.D.Pace suggested

Comment: how can i do that? @ hatik

Comment: See if this works for your subquery: `(SELECT SUM(quoted_price * num_ordered ) FROM tbl_order_line WHERE order_num = tbl_orders.order_num)` I'm not sure if it will, but it's a start.

Comment: @J.D.Pace it worked thank you very much

Comment: Why did you have to use a subquery?

Comment: my professor said me to use only subquerry for that exercise @J.D.Pace

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77874/42

```
SELECT 
tmp2.sums,
tmp2.order_num orders,
tbl_orders.customer_num ,
tbl_orders.order_num ,
tbl_orders.order_date 
FROM tbl_orders 
,
(SELECT  order_num,SUM(quoted_price * num_ordered ) sums FROM tbl_order_line 
 group by order_num
) as tmp2
 group by orders
```